# Get aggregated list of properties from list of Objects(Java 8)

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a class `Division` which is having a list of `Section` as property as below

```
class Division {
    private List<Section> sections;
    // respective getters and setters
}
```

Let's say I have a list of divisions, and I want to get an aggregated list of Sections, I know it can be done using the regular approach as below.

```
List<Division> divisions = getDivisions();
List<Section> sections = new ArrayList<>();
for (Division division : divisions) {

    sections.addAll(division.getSections());
}
```

I want to know if there is any way of doing the same using Java-8 streams.

Comment: `divisions.stream().map(Division::getSections).forEach(sections::addAll);`

Comment: "There are 4 kinds of method reference ... Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type:" `ContainingType::methodName` (from Java docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may do it using the `flatMap` operator. Here's how it looks.

```
List<Section> sections = divisions.stream()
    .flatMap(d -> d.getSections().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This looks more convenient than other answers as I can declare and assign the values in a single line.

Comment: Moreover this is parallel friendly.

Comment: If you prefer method refs: `divisions.stream().map(Division::getSections).flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 2):

You can either map the values:

`divisions.stream().map(Division::getSections).forEach(sections::addAll);`

or simply:

`divisions.forEach(d -> sections.addAll(d.getSections()));`

Answer (score 1):

You can stream over `divisions` list and add the elements to sections as below,

```
divisions.stream().map(ele->ele.getSections()).forEach(sections::addAll);
```